# Fail Installation of Opencart

Tags: failed-installation

On my step 3 of installation Opencart version 1.5.6.1, after i click Countinue, it come with a warning like this:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Error: Table 'oc_product_profile' already exists
Error No: 1050
 CREATE TABLE `oc_product_profile` ( `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `profile_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `customer_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`profile_id`,`customer_group_id`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM COLLATE=utf8_general_ci; ' in /home3/roomba/public_html/2000supply.com/opencart-1.5.6.1/upload/system/database/mysqli.php:40 Stack trace: #0 /home3/roomba/public_html/2000supply.com/opencart-1.5.6.1/upload/system/library/db.php(20): DBMySQLi->query('????CREATE TABL...') #1 /home3/roomba/public_html/2000supply.com/opencart-1.5.6.1/upload/install/model/install.php(26): DB->query(Array) #2 /home3/roomba/public_html/2000supply.com/opencart-1.5.6.1/upload/install/controller/step_3.php(9): ModelInstall->database() #3 [internal function]: ControllerStep3->index(Array, Array) #4 /home3/roomba/public_html/2000supply.com/opencart-1.5.6.1/upload/system/engine/front.php(42): call in /home3/roomba/public_html/2000supply.com/opencart-1.5.6.1/upload/system/database/mysqli.php on line 40

Pls help me how to resolve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

from the error message that said `Table 'oc_product_profile' already exists`, it meant you should remove the table first, then rerun the installation.